# How to get user's birthday but the user isn't me, neither my friends

Tags: facebook-fql, date

I'm trying to get the birthday_date field from the table USER of all users who are attending to a specified event. I'm using the following query:

```
SELECT name, sex, pic_big, profile_url, birthday, birthday_date, meeting_sex FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid FROM event_member WHERE eid=XXXXXXXXXXX AND rsvp_status='attending')
```

But all the returned data in the fields birthday, birthday_date and meeting_sex are null if the user isn't a friend of mine (the access_token was generated using my facebook account). Even if I can see the user's birthday in the user's profile page I cannot retrieve this information with the FQL.

I think it's not a permission issue because I granted all the birthday permissions (the user and friends permissions) and because this permissions are to get the user or friends birthday, not a general user birthday (not me or my friend).

@Black Maggie:
But it's not an event permission. I can't get the birthday_date independent of the event. For example, try running the following query:

```
select birthday_date, profile_url from user where uid = 100002172431048
```

I used an access_token with all the permissions granted. The field birthday_date always return null but when I click to browse the user profile I can see the birthday date.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Some facebook friends' birthdays returning as null but I have the correct API permissions](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/10918919/some-facebook-friends-birthdays-returning-as-null-but-i-have-the-correct-api-pe)

Comment: No, it's not equal to this topic because I can't get the birthday_date of ANY USER that isn't me (the logged in user) or my friend. I just want to get the birthday_date of users that have no friendship with the logged in user.

Comment: Why would you be able to do that? The API doesn't give you access to any users data except your app's users, with their permission, and friends of your app's users, with their permission

Comment: But I can get fields like name, profile_url, pic_big, sex and some others. Why I'm not supposed to get the birhday_date, meeting_sex and some others?

Comment: because name, gender and current profile picture are available publicly via the API, for everything else it's only as documented on the developer site, and generally that means only for your app's users and their friends

Comment: Ok! So there's no way to get the birthday_date (for example) via the API, right?

Answer (score 1):

You are granting OTHER users the right to access YOUR information.

You cannot grant the permission to access OTHER PEOPLE information without THEIR GRANT.

Comment: When I said "I think it's not a permission issue because I granted all the birthday permissions", I was talking about the permissions the user should give to my app in order to use it.

In some cases, I can see the user's birthday by browsing their profile, but when I try to retrieve this information throught the FQL I always get "null".

Comment: Application's grant cannot be applied to event.

Comment: I've answered to you in the main question.